# Did percussion instruments communicate spoken words in click languages?

Tags: theory, rhythm, drums, instruments, history

There are a number of [click languages](https://www.britannica.com/topic/click-languages) in Africa where 'clicks' function as part of their language. It seems like it would be possible to communicate some words with percussion instruments (maybe a shortening of a word)

That then leads me to wonder if early songs with percussions were actually conveying actual words instead of just a beat (similar to how you could do morse code in a beat)

Comment: There are certainly [drums used to convey elements of African speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_drum), but they have nothing to do with click languages.

Comment: I keep considering commenting here and trying to figure out what to say. Although I'm sure it's not your intent, the question comes off as culturally arrogant to some degree, mainly because neither of us knows much about such languages. The article you link seems to say that the "clicks" rarely have meaning *in themselves*, but are just sounds involved in words, so I strongly doubt that an isolated click could convey a meaning. I guess we think of percussion instruments because these clicks are non-pitched (or diffusely pitched) vocal sounds, but there are plenty such in western languages;

Comment: we have plosive and sibilant consonants. These rarely carry meaning in isolation, but they can, at least the sibilants: a protracted "Sssss" suggests a snake; "sh" means be quiet, and "psh" can be communicate that something is being dismissed as nonsense. However, I doubt that a hi-hat, sizzle cymbal, sandpaper block, or other "hissing" percussion sounds could suggest a snake on their own, without some programmatic setup, and more to the point, I know of no case in which instrumental sounds attempt to suggest human phonemes (rather than natural noises like a snake). A steam engine can make a

Comment: "psh" sound near identical to the human dismissive sound, but few make the associative leap. Now, there have been countless times throughout history that instruments have been associated with the *pitch and frequency modulation* of human speech (Steve Reich's *Different Trains*, talking drums, many different chant genres), but there doesn't seem to be an urge to mimic phonemes (aside from speech synthesis, and arguably the wah pedal or cup mutes).

Comment: Anyway, I vote to close because this is essentially a pair of "What if" questions. The first relies more on linguistics than music (if it can be true, it has to do with the function of the clicks in such languages), and the first is one of the "I wonder what prehistoric music was like" questions that were so popular in the 19th century, often rely on false assumptions, and are ultimately unprovable and idle speculation.

Comment: @AndyBonner Though I don't disagree with your comments I've voted to keep the question open. I wonder how much of your objection comes from the question's wording. For example, would it improve things to ask "Is there evidence to suggest ...?"

Comment: @Aaron Agreed, "I wonder if [percussion has ever been used to imitate speech]" could be easily edited into an objective (if very broad) question. For the first question, culturally centrism doesn't have to be intrinsic to the question; you could just ask about instruments abilities to mimic phonemes in any language. (The difficulty is, there are few phonemes that carry or even suggest meanings in any language, and we start wandering into linguistic matters then. Plus we'll probably wind up talking about speech synthesis.)

Comment: I'm not sure who 'we' refers to in your comments. Do you speak african click languages? My question isn't referring to American speech patterns. You can have your opinion, but to me it's not a 'what if' question. I'm specifically trying to learn about music. I'm wondering if our concept of drums and the use of drums actually derives from people trying to express real words or communication.

Comment: `often rely on false assumptions` I'm specifically trying to get more information on a topic I find interesting opposed to rely on assumptions. I had a conjecture. Now I'm researching.

Comment: In the [help](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it specifically says this site is for `enthusiasts` to ask questions about `music history`. I believe this is a valid question for this site

Comment: @AndyBonner this is not a "what if" question, but a question about history. If you are familiar with the research on this topic, and you believe that none of it is actually of useful quality, that could make a good answer. If you believe the question contains misconceptions, clarifying the misconceptions would make a good answer. None of this is a reason to close the question. Don't write answers as comments.

Comment: @user1079505 Maybe nanotek needs to clarify a bit. I took "early songs with percussion" to mean prehistory, since the earliest uses of percussion are certainly long before any documented ones, and by its nature, that realm is limited to speculation, aside from what we can deduce from surviving instruments. People assumed for a long time that drums were the "first instrument," on no basis other than "makes sense, right?," and then a 35K-year-old bone flute was found that became the new "oldest instrument." Speculation is fun, but it's not really compatible with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @user1079505 And yes, I maintain that misconceptions *can* be a close reason, because this question basically asks "Did speech imitation play a role in the birth of percussion," and the only possible answer is "How the hell should anybody know; the 'birth of percussion' is undocumented and is a matter of pure conjecture." And that's not an answer, and neither were my extended comments, and that's why I posted them as such. The fact that this question has gone unanswered for 10 days, on a site where we're all quick to answer anything we can, ought to be evidence that it's unanswerable in its

Comment: current state. I look forward to retracting my close vote and answering if it becomes answerable.

Comment: @AndyBonner reporting on scientific research is compatible with SE. If you're aware that the academic consensus is that origins of music are impossible to research, that would be interesting to report in an answer (but I don't think it's true). But please don't write answers in comments. I guess the reason why the question wasn't yet answered is because our community primarily comprises of musicians rather than researchers. Still I don't see it being off-topic on the site.

Comment: @user1079505 I do not regard the comments I have written on this question to be a satisfactory answer. They are an explanation of my concerns with the question and an encouragement to the OP to edit it. You are welcome to answer yourself.

Comment: @AndyBonner I'd suggest reviewing SO's policy on [when to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment#:~:text=Comments%20are%20temporary%20%22Post%2DIt,they're%20gone%20for%20good.).

Comment: @AndyBonner I've been to an archaeological site where it was strongly believed that one of the instruments in that society was hitting a large rock with a smaller rock and depending on where you hit it, it would sound very different (which I witnessed). I would certainly consider this an early percussion instrument, but this question is not limited to that.

Comment: @AndyBonner I don't currently see any concerns with my question. Just because there are no answers doesn't mean it's not appropriate or it can't be answered. I don't believe your understanding of what this site is agrees with the stated purpose of this site. Archaeology is the study of human history and prehistory. Just because no one was there doesn't mean we can't know or 'All evidence suggests', but it does make it harder. This is a topic very interesting to me. It's not to you. That's fine.